# jQuery toggle horizontal animate

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm new here so I hope I'm doing this right.

I currently working on a easy jQuery functionality, where I have different tabs which will open horizontal. The thing is that I'm having problems to toggle this.

I use a variabel called visible; which is either true or false depending of the state of the element. And this works fine for one element, but if I want to open two elements, I have to double click to first make the value false before it will run.

Could anyone of you provide with a better solution for this?

```
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
    var visible=0;
    function getClickedId(clicked_id) {
        var selectedId = clicked_id;
        $(document).ready(function () {

            if (visible ==0) {
                  $('[name='+selectedId+']').animate({width: 300}, "slow");
                  $('#Wrapper'+selectedId).animate({width: 325}, "slow");
                   visible=1;
            } else {
                  $('[name='+selectedId+']').animate({width: 0}, "slow");
                  $('#Wrapper'+selectedId).animate({width: 25}, "slow");
                  visible=0;
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
```

(Sorry if my code embed isn't correct )

Comment: The [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) guys have a really neat approach to doing this using `data-toggle` / `data-target` attributes. It's probably a bit advanced, but worth a look. [demo](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse), [source](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js).

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var visible=0;
function getClickedId(clicked_id) {
    var selectedId = clicked_id;
    if (visible == 0) {
          $('[name='+selectedId+']').animate({width: 300}, "slow");
          $('#Wrapper'+selectedId).animate({width: 325}, "slow");
          visible=1;
    } else {
          $('[name='+selectedId+']').animate({width: 0}, "slow");
          $('#Wrapper'+selectedId).animate({width: 25}, "slow");
          visible=0;
    }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: That works partially, but then I can't close the opened elements, since the solution you provided the opening function will run even if visible equals 1.

Comment: @user1477205 i didn't understand, what do you mean

Comment: I see you edited the code after my respond. But remove the "document ready" didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var visible=true;
    function getClickedId(clicked_id) {   
        $('[name="'+clicked_id+'"]').animate({width: visible ? 300 : 0}, "slow");
        $('#Wrapper'+clicked_id).animate({width: visible ? 325 : 25}, "slow");
        visible=!visible;
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vHJj7/)
    ​